# Trigger a PowerShell script if code change happens on remote git repo

Tags: powershell, bitbucket, githooks

I wanted to trigger a PowerShell script on my local machine (which will be connected to the internet always) if a code change happens on bitbucket remote git repo for a specific branch.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to declare a Bitbucket Webhook, which, on every push, would send a json payload to a server on your local machine listening for said payload.
Then your local server can call your PowerShell script.

See [BitBucket Manage WebHook](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/manage-webhooks/) in order to declare said hook.
You need to add a webhook listener (here is an [example on MacOs](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/webhook-listener/src)) on your local machine.